# Is $T$ a bijection?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(v) = Av$ where $A$ is given by
>
> $A = \frac 13   \begin{bmatrix}
>         2 & -1 & 2 \\
>         2 & 2 & -1 \\
>         -1 & 2 & 2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$

$T$ is a bijection if it is both injective and surjective. I would prove that it is surjective if T makes up the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ space. The matrix $A$ in fact can be row-reduced to the identity matrix proving this. And I would prove that it is injective by stating that the rows are linearly independent and therefore the $T(A)$ is linearly independent as well. I was wondering if there was like a computational method to prove bijection? I read that if it is bijective, it must have an inverse. Should I find out if A is invertible?

Comment: Thats right. If the matrix is invertible, then it defines a bijection. And inveribility is equivalent to checking determinant being non-zero.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, well so I already found out that the determinant of the matrix is 1. Would that be enough to prove bijection?

Comment: @PVanchinathan How would you explain bijection with a non-zero determinant?

Comment: A square matrix defines a bijection if and only if the matrix has non-zero determinant

Comment: To prove onto you show for a given vector $b$ there is a vector $x$ such that $Ax=b$. This is possible iff $x=A^{-1}b$. As the solution is unique it  also shows injectivity.

Comment: If i was just given a transformation matrix, how would I find an invariant subspace of the transformation? Instead of proving a given invariant subspace?

Comment: Please make that a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**

$dim(V) = dim(W) \implies$ it is sufficient to prove that the linear transformation is $one-to-one$ for it to be an isomorphism.

To show it is $1-1$, you need to show that $N(T)= \big \{0 \big \}$.

Since, as you said, the matrix representation of the linear transformation T can be reduced to $I$, then it is invertible, hence T is $one-to-one$, thus

$\implies$ T is an isomorphism (bijection).

Answer (score -1):

Since A is an n by n matrix, that means proving it is injective implies that it is also surjective (i.e. proving invertibility proves bijection). This works for all linear operators. To show that a matrix is invertible, check out this page on Wolfram Alpha which features a (TFAE:the following are equivalent) list on properties of invertible matrices.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html